# Acumatica - Populating field with values of different fields

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to string together other fields that are on the screen, some are usr fields. I am getting an output into the trace but it is just null or dashes in my case. Even with the dashes still being outputted it is not updating to the field where I want the string to store.
Here is my code:

```
protected void InventoryItem_Descr_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {

      var row = (InventoryItem)e.Row;
      Combined.StockItem.InventoryItemExt rowExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<Combined.StockItem.InventoryItemExt>(row); 
      if (row == null) return;
      if (row != null) {
      string style = row.ItemClassID;
      string metalColor = rowExt.UsrMetalColor;
      string metalType = rowExt.UsrMetalType;
      string diaQuality = rowExt.UsrDiamondQuality;
      string gemColor = rowExt.UsrCenterColor;
      string template = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}";
      string message = string.Format(template, style, metalColor, metalType, diaQuality, gemColor);
      PXTrace.WriteInformation("{0}", message);
      e.NewValue = message;
      }
    }
```

And the trace:

```
Information:    ----
```

The values that I am pulling do have values that are both stored in the database but I would like it to be generated dynamically while the fields are being entered.

I have tried `e.NewValue`, `cache.SetValueExt` as well and just making it equals to message by `row.Descr = message` to make the string display as this fields value.

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: it seems like your extension returns but doesn't have any values? did you debug confirm this? Is the goal of this to auto set the description on new item creation? if so you could add the code to InventoryID (or CD) field updated to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Your FieldDefaulting event handler is working before your usr Fields are getting their value. Try to do the same logic in the RowUpdated event handler

Comment: On which form you have this weird behavior?

Comment: an additional request to the existing question, How can we have the line break after each value (by changing text property it to Multi-line mode).

Comment: Row Updated did work as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code under RowUpdated Event, this should work for you.

```
protected void InventoryItem_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
            var row = (InventoryItem)e.Row;
            Combined.StockItem.InventoryItemExt rowExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<Combined.StockItem.InventoryItemExt>(row); 
            if (row == null) return;
            if (row != null) {
              string style = row.ItemClassID;
              string metalColor = rowExt.UsrMetalColor;
              string metalType = rowExt.UsrMetalType;
              string diaQuality = rowExt.UsrDiamondQuality;
              string gemColor = rowExt.UsrCenterColor;
              string template = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}";
              string message = string.Format(template, style, metalColor, metalType, diaQuality, gemColor);
              PXTrace.WriteInformation("{0}", message);
              cache.SetValueExt<InventoryItem.descr>(row, message);

           }
        }
```